# Does the derivative by extension of Holder continuity coincides original derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B$ be an open bounded convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}-> \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differentiable at any $x_{0}\in\overline{B}$. Assume further that $F\in C^{1,1}\left(B\right)$. Hence by $\left|\partial_{i}F\left(x\right)-\partial_{i}F\left(y\right)\right|\leq K\left|x-y\right|$ for any $x,y\in B$, we have the extended derivative of $\partial_{i}F$ on the boundary of $B$. My question is that: does this derivative coincide with the original derivative of $F$?

Thank you

Comment: I think the answer you want is just: Yes.  What's your definition of being differentiable at a boundary point though?

Comment: $F$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F$ is called to be differentiable at any $x_{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if there is $L$ s.t $$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\dfrac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)+L\left(x-x_{0}\right)}{\left|x-x_{0}\right|}=0.
$$

Comment: I can prove it if we assume $B$ is smooth. Therefore we can have room in a neighborhood of $x_{0}$ on the boundary, In general, I am wondering...

Comment: I see. It has more content than I thought. Perhaps you should give some more context in the question; explain it a little more, or sketch your argument for smooth boundary and why it seems harder when the boundary isn't smooth.